# How to properly pass git ls-files output to Java, if there is any file name with white spaces?

Tags: java, bash, git

I'm trying to handle the output of `git ls-files` in a Java program. Usage is simple:

```sh
java Test $(git ls-files)
```

Test.java:

```java
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String s : args) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

which simply prints out all arguments for now.

Output of `git ls-files`:

```sh
input $.csv
input_1.csv
input_2.csv
input_3.csv
```

Note that the first one, `input $.csv`, has a space in the middle.

My desired output is of course:

```sh
input $.csv
input_1.csv
input_2.csv
input_3.csv
```

However, what Test prints out is:

```sh
input
$.csv
input_1.csv
input_2.csv
input_3.csv
```

The space actually breaks my expectation.

Therefore I tried to `sed` to wrap all file names in quotes:

```sh
java Test $(git ls-files | sed "s/\(.*\)/'\1'/g")
```

The output of `$(git ls-files | sed "s/\(.*\)/'\1'/g")` is as expected:

```
'input $.csv'
'input_1.csv'
'input_2.csv'
'input_3.csv'
```

However, Test still prints out the same output with and without `sed`. What could be wrong with my scripts?

Comment: For programming purposes, use `git ls-files -z` and read the resulting byte stream. File names are zero-terminated, e.g., f o o . t x t NUL q u u x . d a t NUL etc. (Do this with a pipe, not as arguments.)

Comment: `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 java Test`, the `z` vs `0` mismatch is a cultural shift overriding sense and sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve special characters in the output of `git ls-files`, use the `-z` flag.

To pass the null-delimited output of `git ls-files -z` as a list of command line arguments, store the output first in a temporary Bash array, using the `mapfile` builtin (requires at least Bash 4).
Then you can pass the array on the command line,
correctly preserving special characters.

```
mapfile -d '' files < <(git ls-files -z)
java Test "${files[@]}"
```